# Show that $x^4+x+1$ is a prime polynomial over $F_2$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

To prove this, the only idea I had was to divide $x^4+x+1$ by all polynomials over $F_2$ and show that it cannot be evenly divided.

This seems tedious and I am sure there is a more elegant way to prove this. Can anyone give hints or guide me towards a proof?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/511371/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If a quartic polynomial factors over some field, then it has a linear factor and/or an irreducible quadratic factor. Over $F_2$ there are only two (strictly) linear polynomials and only one irreducible quadratic polynomial, namely $x^2 + x + 1$, and these facts together reduce the checking to just a few cases.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like I could do some polynomial division with both the quadratic polynomial and the linear polynomials?

Comment: Existence of linear factors is equivalent to the existence of roots and the given polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: That's one possibility, but for the linear case, recall that $x - a$ divides a polynomial $p(x)$ iff $p(a) = 0$. If a quartic polynomial $p(x)$ is reducible but there's no linear factor, then $p(x)$ factors as a product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials, but over $F_2$ there's only one irreducible quadratic polynomial, so...

Comment: Indeed, @TravisWillse , if product of two quadratics, then of form $\varphi^2=\varphi(x^2)$, so…

Comment: @TravisWillse finally understood. Thank you for the hint. Is there an algorithm to find all elements in a finite field $F_n$?

Comment: ^This is mostly to understand why $x^2+x+1$ is the only quadratic polynomial and not for example $x^2$ or $x^2+1$.

Comment: The polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ is the only quadratic polynomial *irreducible* over $F_2$. The other three quadratic polynomials over $F_2$ (namely, $x^2$, $x^2 + 1$, $x^2 + x$) all factor as a product of linear factors. I'm not sure I understand the question about elements in a finite field. For $F_p$ they're just the residue classes $0, 1, \ldots, p - 1$ modulo $p$. Do you mean to ask about the *polynomials* irreducible over $F_p$?

Answer (score 0):

There is no root, and we need a constant term $1.$ We may simply calculate
$$ \left(x^2 + 1 \right) \left(x^2 + 1 \right) $$
$$ \left(x^2 +x+ 1 \right) \left(x^2 +x+ 1 \right) $$
$$ \left(x^2 + 1 \right) \left(x^2 +x+ 1 \right) $$

Comment: Actually you only need the one in the middle. $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$, so the other two factorizations can be eliminated by the same observation that eliminated the possibility of linear factors. There is only one irreducible quadratic over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen right, that is in the other answer. I mostly wanted to show a beginner that very little theory was required for this problem. My ongoing crusade to get the OP's to actually do something, anything.